# Como hacer una ruta de archivos dinámica

Tags: python, pandas, read

Estuve pensando en como crear un ejecutable con python donde se le solicite al usuario, ingresando el nombre del archivo me creara la ruta.

Este es el código que tengo para lectura normal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría que el usuario con input() ingresara "prueba" y le cargara el archivo. hice:

```
x= input('digite el nombre del archivo: ')
 r'C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Escritorio\Automate\{x}.csv'...
```

Y adquiero un error. Alguno conoce como puedo hacerlo?

Mil gracias por la atención.

Comment: pues la `r` significa que es una cadena *raw-string*, debes colocar `f` que es *format-string*

Comment: Gracias Christian!!
Problema resuelto.